# Is it possible for menu, on hover the background to overlay another menu item?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal menu, It's pure HTML, CSS and Jquery. All the menu works perfect, but the design of the menu has a very stupid separator, which gives me problem. Anyway is it even possible with CSS on hover menu to cover the separator between other menu items?

This is the menu : [image]

This is on hover : [image]

This is the problem : [image]

- Very important! menu is dynamic ( I can't make each one with a given width)
- the separator h.line is a *.png file
- all the menu is pure HTML, CSS, and Jquery (the problem is only in CSS), there is no menu image background, image is only the 'separator line'

CSS code (i think only in this part is the problem):

```
    .white ul.mega-menu li {
    float: left; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.white ul.mega-menu li a {
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    color: #47515c; 
    padding: 0px 15px; 
    text-decoration: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    background: url(../images/top_menu_separate.png) no-repeat right; 


}
.white ul.mega-menu li a.dc-mega {position: relative;}
.white ul.mega-menu li.mega-hover a, .white ul.mega-menu li a:hover {
    color: #47515c;
    background: #dadcde;
    border-left: 1px solid #dadcde;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 5000000;
    overflow: visible;

}
```

HTML:

```
            <div class="white">  
                <ul id="mega-menu-9" class="mega-menu">
                    <li><a href="test.html" class="multi">Expertise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="test.html">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our People</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Our work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Candidates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

I think this is the method:

```
.white ul.mega-menu li:hover
{
    border-left: 1px solid #dadcde;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

The only problem is that, when hover it moves all the menu from the right to the left by 1px, and it look crap... is there a trick?

Comment: could you show some html too?

Comment: yeah, no prob! just a sec

Comment: any more css? that doesn't seem to recreate the problem

Comment: ok ill add all menu CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the problem in a jsFiddle.

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gkgUj/**

Solution:

```
li:hover + li a {
    border-left: 0 none;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
```

**in your case add this**

```
.white ul.mega-menu li:hover + li a {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't help, it only adds a white border on the left.. and no change

Comment: let me explain: menu1 | menu2 |. When i hover the "menu2" i changes the background  only fro menu2, but MENU1 has this "|" separator which is not changing

Comment: I just updated: see what it happens when the border is a different color! in my situation this is the problem, My separator is 1/2 of the horizontal space. And belive my client want it this way :(

Comment: wow, this look much better... Let me insert this in my code! :) Hope this will do the job. If yes you are the best!

Comment: please can you take look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/gkgUj/3/ what iam doing wrong?

Comment: I see in your example it is working! But i cpied your code to my page and its not as yours. Still the 1px is moving on hover... have no idea what is the probleme......... Anyway thank ill try to figure it our

Answer (score 0):

One option is to shift the hovered item to the left by one pixel to cover the separator:

```
.white ul.mega-menu li:hover
{
    border-left: 1px solid #dadcde;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

Another option would be to place the separator on the left side of each item, then replace it with a white border when the item to its left is hovered:

```
.white ul.mega-menu li
{
    background: url(../images/top_menu_separate.png) no-repeat left;
}

.white ul.mega-menu li:hover + li
{
    background: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: first solution is wroking, but I also tried it before, the problem is that when hover mrnu the menu items are moving by 1px. and this is not professional.

Comment: The `border-left` property is intended to counteract the `margin-left` shift, and prevent the menu items and text from shifting when hovered. If you're unable to get that to work, I would suggest implementing the separators in a different way to avoid this problem from the start.